# How can I detect an mass change of an mysql row value?

Tags: php, sql

How would I detect an mass change in an value in an databse? Here's how it looks the first day:

```
USERNAME   FOLLOWERS
timmy.s    125
john.doe   458
alice.m    1543
jay.boo    1949
```

And the second day:

```
USERNAME   FOLLOWERS
timmy.s    125
john.doe   458
alice.m    1683
jay.boo    1963
```

So as you see, **alice.m** got over a 100 followers for one day. So, then I would display some usernames that are "trending" and she will be first, even if **jay.boo** still has more followers from her.

Is there an good way to do this?

Comment: If you don't store the historical information, then you cannot detect the change.  Does your data really have only two columns?  You also need to describe what calculation you really want to describe the change.

Comment: If you add a column for daily additions, you could have an update trigger that increments that column, and a scheduled task to reset the count for all rows at some specific time each day.  How you would do those things depends on the environment you're working in.

Comment: You can have an audit table which can be used to find the followers change differences based on the date / time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, thanks to Gordon Linoff.
I would have an third and fourth column containing last day's followers and last month's followers.

Then, every day it will be calculated what is the difference:

1. Get the difference between today and yesterday
2. Get the difference between today and last month
3. Combine 1. and 2.
4. Sort the numbers by size (ie. 75 will be before 43 and 21)
5. Show the first 3 usernames that have the highest increase rate
   Also, this calculation will apply only for users with an follower number of `website users /4 - (website users /10)` and all of that `/ 100` or more